# Custom Taxonomy Tree view

Tags: theme-development, custom-taxonomy, hierarchical

I have been trying google for this, but not so easy to search for. I have a custom hierarchical taxonomy, something along the lines of:

```
Chainsaws
- Electric
- Petrol
- Other
Grasscutters
- Electric
- Petrol
- Other
```

What I need to do is create an index page, retaining the hierarchical structure.

The closest I have come to doing it is with:

```
$products = get_terms('product-type');
foreach ($products as $product) {
      $out .= $product->name;
}
```

But this just shows the ones in use, and loses it hierarchy :(

Any insights are very welcome.

Thanks in advance

Andy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<?php
$args = array(
  'taxonomy'     => 'product-type',
  'hierarchical' => true,
  'title_li'     => '',
  'hide_empty'   => false
);
?>

<ul>
<?php wp_list_categories( $args ); ?>
</ul>
```

You can use the wp_list_categories function also for taxonomies. http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories

Comment: nice, so simple, yet so many lost hairs :) tyvm

Answer (score 6):

Here is something I whipped up:

```
<?php
//Walker function
function custom_taxonomy_walker($taxonomy, $parent = 0)
{
    $terms = get_terms($taxonomy, array('parent' => $parent, 'hide_empty' => false));
    //If there are terms, start displaying
    if(count($terms) > 0)
    {
        //Displaying as a list
        $out = "<ul>";
        //Cycle though the terms
        foreach ($terms as $term)
        {
            //Secret sauce.  Function calls itself to display child elements, if any
            $out .="<li>" . $term->name . custom_taxonomy_walker($taxonomy, $term->term_id) . "</li>"; 
        }
        $out .= "</ul>";    
        return $out;
    }
    return;
}

//Example
echo custom_taxonomy_walker('category');
?>
```